# JavaScript: access hashes in array by object type when all typeof objects are the same

Tags: javascript, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have an array called RECOGNIZERS.

That looks like this:

```
RECOGNIZERS
[ LuisRecognizer {
    _onEnabled: [],
    _onFilter: [],
    models:
     { '*': 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/CENSOR?subscription-key=CENSOR&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=' } },
  LuisRecognizer {
    _onEnabled: [],
    _onFilter: [],
    models:
     { '*': 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/CENSOR?subscription-key=CENSOR&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=' } },
  RegExpRecognizer {
    _onEnabled: [],
    _onFilter: [],
    intent: '/^(help|demo|\\?)$/i',
    expressions: { '*': /^(help|demo|\?)$/i } },
  RegExpRecognizer {
    _onEnabled: [],
    _onFilter: [],
    intent: '/^env$/i',
    expressions: { '*': /^env$/i } },
  RegExpRecognizer {
    _onEnabled: [],
    _onFilter: [],
    intent: '/^luis_test$/i',
    expressions: { '*': /^luis_test$/i } },
  RegExpRecognizer {
    _onEnabled: [],
    _onFilter: [],
    intent: '/^getLocationId/i',
    expressions: { '*': /^getLocationId/i } },
  RegExpRecognizer {
    _onEnabled: [],
    _onFilter: [],
    intent: '/^setLocationId/i',
    expressions: { '*': /^setLocationId/i } } ]
```

I am running a for loop to collect each of the `LuisRecognizer` models and append it to an array I want to access later. In running that loop, I call my models like so: `RECOGNIZERS[i].models['*]`. However this errors out as soon as it hits the RegExpRecognizer values in the RECOGNIZERS array.

I tried adding the following if statement to try and ignore the non-models. 
That code looks like this:

```
if (typeof RECOGNIZERS[i].models !== 'undefined') {
builder.LuisRecognizer.recognize(args.response, RECOGNIZERS[i].models['*'],
                function (err, intents, entities) {
                    results.push({ response: {entities: entities, intents: intents} });
                    // session.endDialogWithResult({ response: {entities: entities, intents: intents} });
                });
```

But even with that logic check, it still errors out because it seems to override the if statement and still tries to read the RegExpRecognizer values. Here are my console logs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined
    at Array.GetLuisModel (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/dialog.js:354:39)
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.js:67:39
    at next (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.js:92:21)
    at WaterfallDialog.beforeStep (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.js:99:9)
    at WaterfallDialog.doStep (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.js:61:14)
    at WaterfallDialog.dialogResumed (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/WaterfallDialog.js:46:14)
    at Session.endDialogWithResult (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:358:28)
    at PromptText.Prompt.invokeIntent (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/Prompt.js:331:21)
    at PromptText.Prompt.replyReceived (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/Prompt.js:147:18)
    at Session.routeToActiveDialog (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:525:24)
    at Library.selectActiveDialogRoute (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:150:17)
    at Library.defaultSelectRoute (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:301:22)
    at Library.selectRoute (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:96:18)
    at disambiguateRoute (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/UniversalBot.js:398:62)
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/UniversalBot.js:407:21
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/UniversalBot.js:386:19
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:64:17
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizer.js:23:25
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizerSet.js:84:17
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:322:29
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizerSet.js:76:17
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:181:20
    at replenish (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:319:21)
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:330:15
    at Object.async.forEachLimit.async.eachLimit (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:220:35)
    at IntentRecognizerSet.recognizeInParallel (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizerSet.js:66:15)
    at IntentRecognizerSet.onRecognize (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizerSet.js:52:18)
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizer.js:18:23
    at next (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizer.js:50:17)
    at IntentRecognizerSet.IntentRecognizer.isEnabled (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizer.js:53:9)
    at IntentRecognizerSet.IntentRecognizer.recognize (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizer.js:10:14)
    at UniversalBot.Library.recognize (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:59:30)
    at UniversalBot.routeMessage (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/UniversalBot.js:374:14)
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/UniversalBot.js:291:23
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/UniversalBot.js:352:78
    at next (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:88:17)
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:107:17
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/DefaultLocalizer.js:64:17
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at done (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17)
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/DefaultLocalizer.js:61:64
    at tryCallOne (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/bots/location-assistant-bot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)

.getLuisModel - ERROR: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined
.getLuisModel - Session.endConversation()
Session.sendBatch() sending 2 message(s)
```

Comment: That stacktrace is quite large...

Answer (score 2):

Your error is:

> > Cannot read property 'models' of undefined

That means `RECOGNIZERS[i]` is undefined. If you're trying to access an element in the array that is out of range or if there are elements in the array that are undefined you can change your if statement to:

```
if (typeof (RECOGNIZERS[i]||{}).models !== 'undefined') {
```

Or you correctly collect your models using filter:

```
models = RECOGNIZERS.filter(
  function(item){return !!item.models;}
)
```

Comment: I have a suspicion [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1541563) might possibly be related.